# What will be the best way to get only changed objects since specific date-time in priority-web-sdk ERP

Tags: rest, erp, priority-web-sdk

I'm new to priority-web-sdk ERP.
I'm trying to get all the elements that were changed since a specific date-time.
I've tried to use the example from Priority postman collection:

https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/odata/Priority/tabmob.ini/usdemo/ORDERS?$since=2020-06-01T01:15+02:00&$expand=ORDERITEMS_SUBFORM

Unfortunately, the response contains all the records, and doesn't change if I change the date.

Help,
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Odata 'ge' operator (greater/equal) on the field you want to filter by.

For example, to filter by CURDATE field:
`https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/odata/Priority/tabmob.ini/usdemo/ORDERS?$filter=CURDATE ge 2021-06-24T00:00:00Z`

to filter by STATUSDATE field:
`https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/odata/Priority/tabmob.ini/usdemo/ORDERS?$filter=STATUSDATE ge 2021-06-24T00:00:00Z`